# How to add a condition for datatable rowreorder

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui, datatables

I am using the datatable library to display a list of tasks, I have implemented a function that allows to reorder tasks with the RowOrder function, but I want to make a control that allows to order a task only if the date of the task is below the target date.

Comment: Do you have some source code?

Comment: It maybe be better to edit your question to add the new information.